# Not able to Zoom in WebView

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, xamarin, android-webview

I am trying to zoom in/out in Webview control in Xamarin Application for Android. I am trying to get the zoom through multitouch. Below code is not working..

My XAML code:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

WebView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebView.Settings.DefaultZoom = WebSettings.ZoomDensity.Far;
WebView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
WebView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
```

not sure what is wrong... did not find any solution.. Please help.

Note: the zoom functionality works fine for local content but when it loads the url for internet it does not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haved moved the button click functionality to OnCreate method and it is working fine. Thanks guys!!